# Shell script to push docker image to docker hub is stuck

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I'm trying to push the docker image using the shell script, works fine till login it gets logged in but at `push` command it gets stuck, when I run docker `push` command manually it pushes the image but not using shell script.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    set -x #echo on

    variableA=$(docker build -f test.dockerfile --network=host --no-cache -t myrepo/docker-test . | tail -n1 | cut -d " " -f3)

    echo "$variableA"

    docker ps -a

    echo "$DOCKER_HUB_PWD" | docker login --username="$DOCKER_HUB_UNAME" --password-stdin

    tail -n1

    docker push myrepo/docker-test:latest

    tail -n1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by `tail -n1`.

The tail command looking for an input file or data stream.

**Syntax:**

```
$ tail [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

**Examples:**

```
$ tail -n1 FILE.TXT
```

```
cat FILE.TXT | tail -n1
```

Ref: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html